# Either override behaviour of htaccess or a different solution for file access from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

*What it does?*

1. All requests to PDF files are redirected to **validation.php** by
   **htaccess**.
2. **validation.php** takes the log.
3. **validation.php** validates if user logged in or not.
4. If not logged in then kick user out. If logged in then show PDF
   file.

*Problem:* Obviously 4th step (*If logged in then show PDF file*) fails because of the behaviour of htaccess.

*Question:* How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

**HTACCESS:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /validate.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

**validation.php:**

```
//STEP 1) Take a log
$file = 'log.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= (isset($_GET['filename'])) ? $_GET['filename'] : '?';
$current .= " --- " . date('H:i:s') . "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);


//STEP 2) Authenticate login
session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    session_write_close();
    header ('Location: /login.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
    //User should be eble to see the PDF file now.
}
```

Comment: The 4th step is 2 things, what is failing?

Comment: Sorry. PDF file is not shown if user not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `//User should be eble to see the PDF file now.` step, instead of redirecting the user to the pdf file, *simply output the file*. So something like:

```
$file = $_GET['filename'];
$filename = basename($file);

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. Little left though. Now I should try to find a way to get whole URL because the URLs are always different, not only file names. Do you know how I can do that.